# When should I close a FMDatabaseQueue?

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I am using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) in my iOS application to store all kinds of information...

Sometimes it can happen, that multiple threads access my [FMDatabase](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabase.html) at the same time, so I decided to use the [FMDatabaseQueue](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabaseQueue.html) to interact with my SQLite database.

From my point of view, it's not possible to open and close the [FMDatabaseQueue](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabaseQueue.html) underlying [FMDatabase](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabase.html). Is this correct?

Is it okay to create one [FMDatabaseQueue](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabaseQueue.html) instance at the application start, use it every where and from multiple threads and close it at when the app quits?

If not: Can someone explain me how the [FMDatabaseQueue](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabaseQueue.html) works?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. In fact, even in a single threaded app where you're using `FMDatabase`, opening it once is generally advised.

Comment: @Rob strangely the underlying `FMDatabse` is not open when I access it with from `FMDatabaseQueue` methods like `inTransaction` or `inDatabase`. I get the error `The FMDatabase <FMDatabase: 0x7bf23b40> is not open.` I tried adding a line of code `[db open];` at the beginning of the `inTransaction` method and then it worked fine. Do you know why I have to explicitly open the database here? Also, do I need to close it as well if I have opened it explicitly?

Comment: @Sam - This can happen if you did a `close` of a database within a `FMDatabaseQueue` `inDatabase` or `inTransaction`. When you use `FMDatabaseQueue`, you should never call `close` of the `FMDatabase` that is passed to you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the FMDB read me covers these questions for you already.

If you release the queue, it’ll close the connections.